# Copy SQL Server Scheduled Jobs to Oracle Scheduler

Tags: sql-server, scheduled-tasks, oracle19c

I have a requirement of migrating from SQL Server to Oracle 19C. Data migration is done and now I want to know whether there is a mechanism in Oracle to copy SQL Server scheduled job to Oracle Scheduler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non, there is not. You have to understand what each work do and traduce it in the ways of Oracle do, then schedule the work with Oracle Scheduler.